# Cross join in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cross-join

I have a dataframe with 4 columns: Name, Range, Amount, Limit. Name column has 3 names and other columns have 6 values. Now I want to cross join each name to other 6 columns in such a way that the final dataframe must have 18 rows of data, where each name has 6 rows of data.

This is the dataframe:

```
Name    Range   Amount  Limit
John    1.1-3   200000  100000
Adam    2.2-3.7 324000  129000
Prince  4.1-5.5 450000  225000
        6.7-8   574667  276333
        8.1-9   699667  338833
        9.1-10  824667  401333
```

Final result must be

```
Name    Range   Amount  Limit
John    1.1-3   200000  100000
John    2.2-3.7 324000  129000
John    4.1-5.5 450000  225000
John    6.7-8   574667  276333
John    8.1-9   699667  338833
John    9.1-10  824667  401333
Adam    1.1-3   200000  100000
Adam    2.2-3.7 324000  129000
Adam    4.1-5.5 450000  225000
Adam    6.7-8   574667  276333
Adam    8.1-9   699667  338833
Adam    9.1-10  824667  401333
Princy  1.1-3   200000  100000
Princy  2.2-3.7 324000  129000
Princy  4.1-5.5 450000  225000
Princy  6.7-8   574667  276333
Princy  8.1-9   699667  338833
Princy  9.1-10  824667  401333
```

This is what I tried

```
df1 = data['Name']
 
df2 = data[['Range','Amount','Limit']]

df1['key'] = 1
df2['key'] = 1

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on ='key').drop("key", 1)
```

Comment: Your input(s?) is unclear, can you please provide a `DataFrame` constructor?

Comment: Hope now the input is understandable

Comment: It is still ambiguous, that's why I requested code. What is the output of `data.to_dict('list')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there, you first need to get rid of the empty values in "Name". You can also use `how='cross'` in the merge:

```
out = (data.loc[data['Name'].ne(''), ['Name']]
           .merge(data.drop(columns='Name'), how='cross')
      )
```

*I assumed that the empty cells are empty strings (`''`), if you have NaNs, replace `.ne('')` by `.notna()`.*

Output:

```
      Name    Range  Amount   Limit
0     John    1.1-3  200000  100000
1     John  2.2-3.7  324000  129000
2     John  4.1-5.5  450000  225000
3     John    6.7-8  574667  276333
4     John    8.1-9  699667  338833
5     John   9.1-10  824667  401333
6     Adam    1.1-3  200000  100000
7     Adam  2.2-3.7  324000  129000
8     Adam  4.1-5.5  450000  225000
9     Adam    6.7-8  574667  276333
10    Adam    8.1-9  699667  338833
11    Adam   9.1-10  824667  401333
12  Prince    1.1-3  200000  100000
13  Prince  2.2-3.7  324000  129000
14  Prince  4.1-5.5  450000  225000
15  Prince    6.7-8  574667  276333
16  Prince    8.1-9  699667  338833
17  Prince   9.1-10  824667  401333
```

Reproducible input:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', 'Adam', 'Prince', '', '', ''],
                     'Range': ['1.1-3', '2.2-3.7', '4.1-5.5', '6.7-8', '8.1-9', '9.1-10'],
                     'Amount': [200000, 324000, 450000, 574667, 699667, 824667],
                     'Limit': [100000, 129000, 225000, 276333, 338833, 401333]})
```